# Is there a Bootstrap plugin that provides a combination of a dropdown menu and list box?

Tags: css, html

For my website, I require to have a select box. I am using Bootstrap, but it only provides a dropdown menu, which is not exactly what I need.

Is there a plugin available that provides a select box?

Here is a GIF showing exactly what I am trying to achieve: https://gyazo.com/2d16dba01cd3eb5860618b35909b9885

So basically it's a combination of the Bootstrap's Drop-down menu and HTML list box.

Comment: is this what you are looking for`<select class="form-control"><option>foo</option></select>` ?, check this advance component also https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Comment: Hi Akshay! Yes, something like that. It needs to have a mix of dropdown menu and what you posted. I want a dropdown menu where initially it says "Your preferred contact method" then it's a dropdown menu where you can select 'by phone' or 'by email' and once you select it, it would show that option. Like this: https://gyazo.com/2d16dba01cd3eb5860618b35909b9885

Comment: try https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Comment: try `<select class="form-control"><option value="">---SELECT PAYMENT OPTION---</option><option value="mail">By Main</option>...</select>`

Comment: Yes! Got it working. Last question. Will I be able to use this together with Jquery & PHP to mail the answer to an email?

Comment: sure you can, and do check the library link that I have posted or that's there in the answers all are same...

Comment: try added HTML5 Validation `<select class="form-control" required><option value="">---SELECT PAYMENT OPTION---</option><option value="mail">By Main</option>...</select>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes , select box available in bootstrap go through this link in and finds multipal select box https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Comment: That's what I am trying now. I think I can use the placeholder one to achieve what I want!

Comment: i think your question is solve right any question plz ask question.

Comment: no any plugins ,you can use bootstrap .css and .js  so you can easily run this code.

Answer (score 2):

Here i will show you some plug in for **Bootstrap - Select**

Github : [Bootstrap - Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)

Comment: Great plugin! Thanks for suggestion, using this now.